# Why some elements of the response object are missing? Requests module

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

As I've recently started learning web scraping, I thought I would try to parse an HTML table from this [site](https://vstup.edbo.gov.ua/statistics/requests-by-university/?qualification=1&education-base=40) using requests and bs4 modules.

I know I need to access `td class` from `tbody` -- this is how a web page looks like at least:

[image]

When I try, though, it doesn't seem to work properly as it only captures `td class` from `thead` and not from `tbody`. Hence, I cannot capture anything but the headers of the table.

I assume it has something to do with `requests` module.

```
url = 'https://vstup.edbo.gov.ua/statistics/requests-by-university/? 
qualification=1&education-base=40'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

The result is as follows (pasting table-related part):

```
<table id="stats">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="region">Регіон</td>
        <td class="university">Назва закладу</td>
        <td class="speciality">Спеціальність (спеціалізація)</td>
        <td class="average-ball number" title="Середній конкурсний бал">СКБ</td>
        <td class="requests-total number">Усього заяв</td>
        <td class="requests-budget number">Заяв на бюджет</td>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

So the `tbody` elements are missing in my response object, while they are present in the code of the web page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I view the source of that URL I don't see any content in the table body. Requests is accurately showing you what the server is sending.

Comment: @holdenweb , thanks for the reply. I provided a link to the screenshot of the url code. It doesn’t seem to be empty

Comment: It seems likely from a less superficial examination of the source that the page is delivered to the client, where the table is populated by client-side scripting. If this is indeed the case, the easiest way I've found to extract content is to use Selenium under Python control to gain access to the displayed page contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Holdenweb suggested trying Selenium and everything worked.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://vstup.edbo.gov.ua/statistics/requests-by-university/? 
qualification=1&education-base=40'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:/folder/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
```

after that, I used BeautifulSoup and managed to parse the web page.